# Python print special formatting with dictionary key not working

Tags: python, formatting

I'm trying to print with special formatting based on dictionary keys. Below is my code that throws a TypeError: Format requires a mapping.

Someone told me that keys cannot be integers, so I changed that to string numbers. I was also hoping to put a variable inside %(__)s like %(your_choice)s, but he told me you cannot have variables inside special format (is this true?).

```
your_choice = "one"
yourOS_dict = {"one": "MacOS", "two": "Windows", "three": "Linux"}
print("You chose option # %s. %(one)s !" % (your_choice, yourOS_dict))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why don't you use `"... %s !" % ( yourOS_dict[your_choice] )`

Comment: if you are using python3 you can use fstring like this
print(f"You chose option # {your_choice}. {yourOS_dict['your_choice']}s !")

Comment: I'm not sure if you can mix `%s` with `%(one)s`.  It may expect one dictionary for all `%s` - and you would have to add `your_choice` to `yourOS_dict = {"one": "MacOS", "two": "Windows", "three": "Linux", 'your_choice':your_choice}`, and then use `%(your_choice)s. %(one)s !" % yourOS_dict`

Comment: Whoever told you that dictionary can't have integer keys, they are wrong.
Here is a reference - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is true. You cannot have variables inside special format. The % items are just a place holder for the variables you would substitute into the string.

The correct use would be

```py
your_choice = "one"
yourOS_dict = {"one": "MacOS", "two": "Windows", "three": "Linux"}

# Gets the value for the key "one"
selection = yourOS_dict[your_choice]

print("You chose option # %s %s !" % (your_choice, selection))
```

This would output

```py
> You chose option # one MacOS
```